# SELECT on data that might be under SERIALIZABLE lock

Tags: sql-server

I have a part of application that constantly updates values in table rows (1-100 rows).
Since this data integrity is important i am using SERIALIZABLE lock on transaction in functions reading and updating those rows.

Now my question is if i execute a simple read only SELECT (without lock) on rows that is currently used by a transaction i could probably get a DEADLOCK exception right?
So would that mean that i would still need a retry mechanism in case of DEADLOCK even in case of simple SELECT?

Comment: For the read SELECT what i really need is to return the last committed state of records so basically i dont care about integrity at all.

Comment: it is but just in some cases. e.g i have a functions that update some row status, when called they ensure that no other transaction is either reading or updating those records. Now i would need to query the current statuses    and i dont care about data integrity at all.

Comment: MSSQL database.

Comment: I'm not necessarily questioning the need for SERIALIZABLE isolation level, but I'll just say that it's unusual to actually need it. What specific read phenomena are you trying to prevent (i.e. non-repeatable/phantom reads)?

Comment: I am using it get a consistent state in login system. It is a requirement for consistency not to allow any other transaction either read or write the rows and as i understand this can only be done with SERIALIZABLE lock?

Comment: Reads don't, to my knowledge, ever block other reads. And why should they? My reading of the data doesn't affect your ability to read the data nor does it affect *what* you're actually reading. Now, as for how writes and reads interact, it depends on what your definition of "consistency" is and your tolerance for the read phenomena I mentioned above is. So far, that has been talked about in generalities. Instead of assuming you need SERIALIZABLE, talk about what what the specific business requirements are and we can help you to make an informed decision as to what isolation level you need.

Comment: Ok lets have a simple example with user login state.

1) T1 Tries to login user, first it selects user state ROW and if user is not logged in runs an UPDATE statement.
2) T2 At starts at middle of T1 opeation and tries to do same thing.

Would i be able to ensure that that T1&T2 would not do same thing and produce invalid states with other than SERIALIZABLE lock ?

Answer (score 3):

Now that I know what your specific business scenario is (from the comments), here's how you'd do something like what you're proposing without having to implement serializable isolation

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateUserState] (@UserID int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT [State]
        FROM [dbo].[UserState] WITH (UPDLOCK)
        WHERE [UserID] = @UserID;

        IF ([State] = 'logged out')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [us]
            SET [State] = 'logged in'
            FROM [dbo].[UserState] AS [us]
            WHERE [UserID] = @UserID;
        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Note that this is simplified, but presents the main idea. The `UPDLOCK` hint on the `SELECT` statement is the key. It says "try to select data as through I was going to do an update (which you are! just later) and keep it until the end of the transaction". In your example, if T2 comes in and T1 is still running, T2 will be unable to obtain the update lock and will thus wait until T1 is complete (either successfully or no). Also note that setting the transaction isolation level explicitly is just for completeness; `READ COMMITTED` is the default in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes you totally right the key is UPDLOCK. After doing some research i now realize that. Now the only thing left is to find how to do SELECT with update lock in Entity Framework.

Comment: You can use stored procedures with EF. When you need this level of control, it's a good use case.

Comment: To be honest i prefer to avoid them so i will probably just use a normal SQL statement to fetch data. Still its strange EF misses this functionality as it seems it would be pretty standard thing to do.

Comment: It seem i will still need a SERIALIZABLE transaction as PHANTOM rows can occur. Since when in transaction i will need to lock range of user states being modified or created.  

E.g  SELECT [State]
        FROM [dbo].[UserState] WITH (UPDLOCK)
        WHERE [UserID] = @UserID;

This will select USER STATE but if none exist transaction will try to insert a new one but this wont block a second transaction doing the same thing.

Am i correct in my assumption?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. In the strictest sense, you're right; if you look at only this table and it's possible that a record for this user doesn't exist. But you have options. If UserState ties back a User record, you can UPDLOCK select *that* as a proxy. Alternatively, if you create a UserState record whenever you create a user, it's guaranteed to be there and you don't need to worry about phantom data. Anyways, the point is there are multiple ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Well by design i cannot create those records for the user as they created when user is actually logged in and modified when logged out. Basically the entities i am referring to are representing a user session so if there is no user login then there is no user session. With each login new Session  is created and i need to ensure that only one will be created by transactions.

So what you saying is i should use the UPDLOCK hint to lock the users right before i am about to modify their Session?

Comment: It *should* work. Alternatively, you could just do the SERIALIZABLE transaction with just the select and update. The point is that you want to make that transaction as small as possible because as you start requiring more/higher guarantees from your isolation level you decrease concurrency. Test whatever approach under (simulated) high load and see how it performs.

Comment: Will do, in any case thank you very much for your help!